# Removing the ith element from array so the time complexity does not depend on array size

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity

Yesterday I have took my Analysis of Algorithm exam in which the question was
 ***Describe how one can implement each of the following operations on an array so that the time it takes does not depend on the array size n.***

- Delete the ith element of an array of size n.
- Delete the ith element of a sorted array, where the array remains in
  sorted order after the deletion.

For the first part we can swap the ith value with the last one , thats what I wrote, while doing this for the sorted array will not work because array will get unsorted. 
Now the question are, how one can implement this for sorted array? Is it possible to do this without any drawbacks? Can we do it in better way for unsorted array?

Comment: 1. does 'array' has to be an ARRAY (continuous block split into elements of the same size) or is it any collection which provide indexed items?
2. when you 'delete', do the indexes shift ?

Comment: Array is collection which provides indexes items.  Index shifting is dependent on array size we have to find a way in which we can delete value without shifting  indexes

Comment: The second question is either very misleading, or you're describing it to us in a misleading way, because (assuming the usual definition of "array" and "sorted", and that no auxiliary data structures are allowed) it has no solution.  It's simple to demonstrate that n updates (and thus O(n) time) can be forced: Just remove the first element of an array of n distinct elements.

Comment: I have posted the question as it was. I myself think that there is no perfect solution for the sorted array using a sentinel value is just a workaround @j_random_hacker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the purpose of the question was to give you an idea of the difference between Arrays and Lists. In the former, you have arbitrary access, but deletions and additions will require shifting of indices. In lists, however, you can add/delete nodes in constant time once you reach them. However, reaching takes O(n) since you don't have arbitrary access. If that's the idea of your question-maker, I think he/she expects you to create a data structure like a List, but with indices - like Java's ArrayList.

However, you can also solve this with an array by simply keeping a list of indices that are deleted. If array[i] is to be deleted, simply keep a new list "deletedIndices" and add "i" to it. Thus, deletion will take constant time and space. There won't be any need to add a sentinel.

EDIT: To answer you question on my comment, no, skipping will not cost O(n). It's a simple list update. Also, even though it's not what the question is, it's worthy to know that all future traversals of the array will require traversal of the new list as well to know when to skip. This can be done efficiently if the list is kept sorted at all times. We can determine which position to place the new incoming object by simply traversing the list once. This will take O(n). So, to sum up, deletion occurs in constant time, but traversal will still take O(n) + O(n) = O(n) - the first big oh for original array traversal, second for list traversal

Comment: Your deletion list idea might help in some cases, but actually it worsens the access time for an arbitrary array element from O(1) to an *unbounded* time (not even O(n)): there could have been an arbitrarily large number of insertions and deletions performed in the past, and to access a given index i, we need to examine every element in this unboundedly large number of elements in deletedIndices.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Totally agree with your point, but the question inccluded a one-time-deletion. So the deletedList approach can easily work. As for your query, might I suggest limiting the list to a fixed size? After this size is reached, instead of adding to the list further, we actually shift the array elements to account for the additions and deletions. We then empty the list. Thus, access time is now bounded in the worst case. Do you have any other methods in mind?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're interpreting the question to mean that only a single deletion (at some position i) would ever take place.  While that's perhaps a technically valid interpretation, I don't think it's the intended or best one (for example, because *both* questions could then be solved in the exact same way).  But if that is your interpretation, then why do you talk about a *list* called "deletedIndices"?  Wouldn't it just be a single value, "deletedIndex"?  (Which could assume some special value, e.g. -1, to indicate the single deletion has not yet taken place.)

Comment: I think your ideas for emptying out the list of deleted indices are good.  If you empty the list out (and actually shift array elements around) whenever it gets to length k, then you get an algorithm with O(k) access time and amortised O(n/k) time per deletion: while it takes O(n) time to "clean up", there will always be at least k deletions between "cleanups".  If you choose k = O(sqrt(n)) you can get (amortised) O(sqrt(n)) for both; if you choose k = O(n) you can get (amortised) constant-time deletions, though with O(n) access time.

Comment: I used list in a more general sense - it can have 1 or more elements. Also, this approach, while doable for the first question, is not efficient. OP's approach to simply swap with first/last element and keep a note of start/end indices is much better since it requires lesser extra memory. I assumed that since its an exam, they are trying to get the best answer from students. Also the point of the question is, I think, to show how the 1st answer's approach will not work for 2nd

Comment: @j_random_hacker amortized O(n/k) is exactly what I had in mind!

Comment: My question is *why* you used the word "list" at all -- if you had really interpreted the question to mean "a single deletion, ever" then you don't *need* to talk about a list, because a single deletion can be recorded in a single scalar variable.  Also under the assumption that there is only a single deletion ever, your "deletedIndices" list (which will be of size at most 1) will have the same time and space complexity as the OP's for the first question.

Comment: I think there is some miscommunication happening from my side. I assumed the possibility of 1 or more deletions, but I showed the working for every single deletion. So, to clear things out, 1 single deletion will take, like you said, 1 variable and will be similar to OPs solution to the first question. But, assuming there may be more deletions in the future, I maintain a list. Its OK if the list only ever contains 1 element. Hope this clears your doubts...

Comment: "But, assuming there may be more deletions in the future, I maintain a list." -- good, that means we did interpret the question the same way.  What was confusing me is that in your first comment, you wrote "..., but the question inccluded a one-time-deletion. So the deletedList approach can easily work.", which I interpreted to be an argument against my claim of unbounded time complexity.  Do we agree then that, without the periodic cleanup operations, your deletedIndices approach has unbounded time and space complexity?  If so then I have no further complaints ;-)

Comment: Of course! There is no doubt that "access time" is unbounded! But the question was to design such that "deletion does not depend on size of the array" which my original solution does. The cleaning of list is a workaround to improve the access time, but that is besides OP's question. The underlying point that I feel OP should take from this discussion is that we are improving deletion at the cost of other operations. So this solution is ideal for a system wherein n(deletions) >> n(additions) or n(access time)

Comment: I see, in that case the misunderstanding was on my part.  Thanks for being patient :)

Comment: Discussion in comments make more sense than answer also clear the answer

Answer (score 1):

**a.** Replace the ith element with the last element and decrease the array
size by 1.

**b.** Replace the ith element with a special symbol that cannot be a value
of the array’s element (e.g., 0 for an array of positive numbers) to mark
the ith position as empty. (This method is sometimes called the “lazy
deletion”.)

Answer (score -1):

Replace the *i*th element with a special symbol that cannot be a value of the array's element (eg., 0 for an array of positive numbers) to mark the *i*th position as empty. (This method is sometimes called the "lazy deletion".)